# What happens to status variable in various situations of wait(&status) system call?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, wait

(1) Assume, that main process calls `fork()`, and it returns -1, so process have no children.
After this call in main process called `wait(&status)`, and according to manuals it will return -1. Will 'status' variable stay unchanged, as before call?

(2) Having this situation from (1), if right after `wait(&status)` line, there is a line `status = WEXITSTATUS(status)`, will 'status' variable change then?

```
int status = 0;
  if (fork()!=0) {
  wait(&status);
  status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

Comment: Those are interesting questions; what, other than posting here, have you done to try and answer them?

Comment: searching google, offcourse :) And since I can not do simulation for this situation, I am asking. Nothing specific in man's about exact behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Grammar problems.

Comment: It seems intuitively obvious that the status variable won't be modified if the function fails, but I don't see anything at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html that says so explicitly. Language-lawyers might have fun with this one.

Comment: For practical purposes, you *can* easily test how your current system behaves. Just go ahead and call `wait` in a new process with no children. There's no way it can distinguish between a process that has no children because a fork failed, a process that has no children because it never called fork, and a process that has no children because they've already exited (and cleaned up by a previous wait)

Comment: Thank you!
I have just tried this example:

    ` int status;
      printf("%d\n",status);
      wait(&status);
      printf("%d\n",status);
      status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
      printf("%d\n",status);`
and without the line `status = WEXITSTATUS(status);` `status`stay unchanged, but with it each run of the program its different. Any ideas why? ('status' always has same value when sent to WEXITSTATUS)

Comment: P.S. When `status` initialized, it is always 0 in code from previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: undefined behaviour. There is no guarantee that status is unchanged if waitpid failes

2: yes, status = WEXITSTATUS(status); will replace the value in status. (Specifically, WEXITSTATUS should mask away all upper bits of the value)